# How to use the Vue.js Chrome devtools with jsFiddle?

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, google-chrome-devtools, jsfiddle

I am learning [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) and am playing around with it using [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). Vue.js is natively supported by jsFiddle.

However, I can not use the [Chrome Browser's vue.js dev-tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) with jsFiddle, as it's not detecting it. The little "V"-icon always stays disabled, saying "vue.js not detected".

Now, the problem is, that jsFiddle renders the result in an HTML `iframe`, and dev-tools as is does not check any `iframe` for Vue.js apps, as for example, mentioned in this [github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/353).

I never managed to escape the `iframe`. Even when opening the framed content's URL in a new window, the resulting HTML page again contains an `iframe`.

**How to use the Vue.js dev-tools with jsFiddle?**

Answer (score 7):

My solution to this is using the [standalone dev-tools with node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/devtools), as proposed by [Geoff Baum](https://github.com/gabaum10) in his [comment on github.](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/353#issuecomment-393555401)

Just install Vue Developer Tools globally:

```
npm install -g @vue/devtools
```

Then run it globally:

```
vue-devtools
```

In your fiddle, right on top, just add the proposed script URL:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8098"></script>
```

Here's a working jsFiddle, using the standard example: https://jsfiddle.net/suterma/zr2vtg84/4/

```
<script src="http://localhost:8098"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
....
</div>
```

Here's how it looks:

[image: jsFiddle with connected, local Vue Developer Tools]