# Does Vue dev tool work with Google Application Script web?

Tags: vue.js, google-apps-script, web-applications, vue-devtools

I am getting `Vue.js not detected` for the latest Vue and the latest plugin version for both firefox and chrome browsers.

I am getting "not detected" for both

1. my Google Application Script web
   https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxfIx0rZbrlFcK0frgdqxb7QjXKkbPEGL0DHqRWpvgjGrDgc2fZ2NYBxHJomFu0tt-EPQ/exec
2. and this sample table Vue application I found https://ygnl5.csb.app/

BUT if I do mouse right button click on both pages and then inspect

1. does **NOT** show Vue tab
2. **SHOWS** Vue tab

So my conclusion is that iFrame that Google adds is causing the troubles

If I use the same code from my GAS application locally Vue is even detected

The code is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
// Vue.config.devtools = true
    const app = Vue.createApp({
      data() {
          return {
              vueWorks: true,
              product: 'Socks',
              inStockCount: 50,
          }
      }
    }) 
    const mountedApp = app.mount('#app')
  })
  </script>
    <div id="app">
<p v-if="vueWorks">If you see this Vue works</p>
<p v-else>But if you see this then well Vue does not work</p>

      <h1>{{ product }}</h1>
      <input :value="inStockCount"> <!-- src attribute bound to the image data -->
<p v-if="inStockCount > 10">In Stock</p>
<p v-else-if="inStockCount <= 10 && inStockCount > 0">Almost sold out!</p>
<p v-else>Out of Stock</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's currently no `iframe` support for the Vue DevTools browser extension. Someone reported the [same Vue DevTools issue with GAS](https://github.com/vuejs/devtools/issues/353#issuecomment-370982019), caused by the lack of `iframe` support.

There was a [promising look into a fix/workaround](https://github.com/vuejs/devtools/pull/361#issuecomment-419184978), some [feedback to use *remote devtools* instead](https://github.com/vuejs/devtools/pull/361#issuecomment-475531941), and then the [issue closed on 24 May 2021](https://github.com/vuejs/devtools/pull/361#event-4789062768) without any change made.

The "remote devtools" is the standalone Electron app for Vue DevTools (see [usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59823141/6277151)). However, your mileage may vary for `iframe`s.